# I have a form in php on the page and they are not entered

Tags: php

on the next page: http://www.giselamarianaalonso.com.ar/contacto
Not receiving form input and I cannot find the error in the code. But I don't understand what the problem can be.

```
    <?php
$MailToAddress = "giselamarianaalonso@gmail.com";
$MailSubject = "mensaje recibido desde nuevo sitio";
 if (! isset($MailFromAddress) ) {
 $MailFromAddress = "info@giselamarianaalonso.com.ar";
 }
 
$Header = "CONTACTO";
$Message = $Footer = "";
 
 if (!is_array($_POST))
 return;
 reset($_POST);
 while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST)) {
 $GLOBALS[$key] = $val;
 $val=stripslashes($val);
 $Message .= "$key = $val\n";
 }
 
 if ($Header) {
 $Message = $Header."\n\n".$Message."\n\n";
 }
 $REMOTE_USER = (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]))?$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]:"";
 $REMOTE_ADDR = (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]))?$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]:"";
 $Message .= "REMOTE USER: ". $REMOTE_USER."\n";
 $Message .= "REMOTE ADDR: ". $REMOTE_ADDR."\n";
 
 if ($Footer) {
 $Message .= "\n\n".$Footer;
 }
 
mail( "$MailToAddress", "$MailSubject", "$Message", "From: $MailFromAddress");
header ("Location: http://www.giselamarianaalonso.com.ar");

?>
```

Comment: `each` is deprecated and removed in `v8`